# Why my app crashed when upload a bytearray image?

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

So I want to upload the image shown in imageView to Firebase Storage, but Firebase Storage only accepts bytearray and uri files when upload. So I converted the imageview into bytearray. The code is working fine but when I upload the picture on my phone, the app crash. Anyone knows why? The code is shown below:

```
    imagePicker = findViewById(R.id.edit_cover_picture)
    val bitmap = (imagePicker as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream)
    val image = stream.toByteArray()
    imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.drawable.cover_picture}")
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("coverPicture/"+auth.currentUser?.uid)
    storageReference.putBytes(image).addOnSuccessListener
```

Below is the error logcat:

```
2022-06-23 20:48:32.566 21992-21992/com.example.gesit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.gesit, PID: 21992
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    at com.example.gesit.EditInfoUsaha.uploadCoverPic(EditInfoUsaha.kt:253)
    at com.example.gesit.EditInfoUsaha.onCreate$lambda-1$lambda-0(EditInfoUsaha.kt:167)
    at com.example.gesit.EditInfoUsaha.$r8$lambda$a3cjJsmtqFylqQUYq8anKkSMPYw(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.gesit.EditInfoUsaha$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, error logcat has been provided.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Paste the relevant lines from the logcat as text in a code block. No images please.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Error logcat provided.

Comment: @Tommy- Is this `R.id.edit_cover_picture` the id of your image view?

Comment: try this `val bitmap = (imagePicker.drawable as BitmapDrawable).getBitmap()`